# jQuery, Animate opacity to 1 then remove the opacity property to make it better looking on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried the jQuery fadeIn animation in all browsers and it work good, but not that much on IE. the Alpha png images are so creepy after appending the CSS opacity, but i have an idea and i don't know how to implement it using jQuery.

The idea is to fadeIn the element and when the animation is finished it will automatically remove the opacity property in order to make the picture quality better.

How to do that?

Note: i'm using Animate and not FadeIn.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(selector).animate({opacity: 1}, function() {
  $(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
});
```

The filter IE uses is what causes ClearType to basically turn off.  Remove that style attribute after the fade completes like the code above to restore ClearType to working order.  You can also find replacement `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()` and `fadeTo()` methods that deal with this issue here: http://malsup.com/jquery/fadetest.html

Comment: This jQuery bug was there in 1.4.2 and it's still there in 1.4.3

Comment: @Marco - It's not a jQuery bug though  (IMO), it's just not a feature.  It's *completely* IEs fault that it can't handle opacity and cleartype together correctly, every other browser does so fine.

Comment: @Nick Craver: but actually these libraries (like jQuery and YUI) should be there in 1st place to create a layer that is cross-browser. If I write $(somelement).css('opacity', ''); I would expect both IE and any other browser to remove opacity style, and I expect the library code to handle also any IE issues.

Comment: @Marco - while I don't disagree with the sentiment, I do disagree that I should have worse performance for all opacity animations for all *other* browsers because of a bug in IE...if it wasn't expensive to do either way then sure, but it is :)

Comment: @Nick Craver: well I don't follow you here, it's not my sentiment, look at jQuery code for function likes offset (and many other ones), you will see dozens of hacks in code to handle IE issues. By following your philosophy do you think all those hack should be removed to increase performance on other browsers?! Anyway +1 to your answer I'm using it in standard Javascript.

Comment: @Marco - yes there are IE workarounds everywhere...that's why we use the abstraction layer, but `.animate()` in particular is called *everywhere*, and runs every 13ms per frame...so any cost increase there is much more expensive than pretty much anywhere else in jQuery core, aside from selectors themselves.

Answer (score 6):

If you set the opacity with jQuery to begin with (as 0):

```
$(object).css("opacity", 0);
```

then after you fade it in, you can just:

```
$(object).fadeIn("slow", function(){ 
    $(object).css("opacity", "");
});
```

as the above answer didn't work for me in IE <= 8