# CSS Jquery - When I change background color the text becomes fuzzy in IE6?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I was playing around with this script of auto scrolling text. You can check out the code here:

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/simple-jquery-spy-effect/

Then I changed the background color to white - and all the text started looking fuzzy and messed up - If I change it to any light color - it appears all messy.

This is the portion where I changed the background color in the code:

```
#sidebar {
    color: grey;
    background: #FFF;
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 24px;
    padding:15px 10px 10px;
    width:500px;
}
```

I have noticed this in one other site even on IE7. Any idea why a simple change in background color messes up the text.

I used IE tested to test on IE6 browser
http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Thanks

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you call "fuzzy" ?

Comment: I can't tell the problem is css.. I have modified the background and it works well... http://jsbin.com/iciwi3.... define "FUZZY".. show it...

Comment: Can we attach a screenshot - by fuzzy I mean the text is not readable......
@Reigel - did you test in IE6 browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you certain you're not using IE css filters in an element further up the tree, such as alpha transparency? They can make text blurry/fuzzy when [ClearType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType) (font smoothing on LCD monitors) is enabled, especially for bolded text, so much so that cleartype was disabled for elements which use CSS filters in IE7+.

See also http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/08/31/730887.aspx

**EDIT:** Here's an example of what you could do to remove the filter after the items have first faded in:

```
// increase the height of the NEW first item
$insert.animate({ height : height }, 1000).animate({ opacity : 1 }, 1000);
```

might go to

```
// increase the height of the NEW first item
$insert.animate({ height : height }, 1000).animate({ opacity : 1 }, 1000,
    function() {
        if ($.browser.msie) {
            $(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
        }
    });
```

See also [jQuery, Animate opacity to 1 then remove the opacity property to make it better looking on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603961/jquery-animate-opacity-to-1-then-remove-the-opacity-property-to-make-it-better-l)

Comment: Thanks David, I've not added anything to that piece of code except change the background color to white.

Comment: debugging the rolling elements in the IE dev toolbar, they have a `filter: alpha(opacity=100);` after they've finished fading, so that looks like the problem - you may be able to delete the "`filter`" CSS property to turn off the DirectX/ClearType blurriness once the "fade in" animation has finished :-P

Comment: David - are you referring to this line in the javascript code $list.find('> li').filter(':gt(' + (limit - 1) + ')').remove();

Comment: no, the `.filter` in that line has nothing to do with the CSS `filter`, it's for searching through elements which meet the conditions of a selector in JQuery (http://api.jquery.com/filter/), see my edited answer for an example of how to remove CSS filters

Comment: hey david - thanks - that almost did the trick in IE6 - the text appears fuzzy but a second later becomes clear - but after making that change - the scrolling has stopped working in firefox and chrome - the first element appears and then the list stops scrolling

Comment: @Gubloo: sorry, that line only worked in IE - I've edited the answer to fix that. There probably isn't any way of fixing the blurriness in IE6 except by disabling fading in/out by removing the `.animate({ opacity...)` parts though

Comment: That will work for me - thank you so much for taking the time to help me - appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I will finish the **David M** Question.
You have to remove the IE CSS Filter property.

I see that you are using jQuery.

If you are using fadeIn, fadeOut and fadeTo functions, add this to your code:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.FadeIn = function(speed, callback) {
$(this).fadeIn(speed, function() {
if(!$.support.opacity)
$(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
if(callback != undefined)
callback();
});
};
$.fn.FadeOut = function(speed, callback) {
$(this).fadeOut(speed, function() {
if(!$.support.opacity)
$(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
if(callback != undefined)
callback();
});
};
$.fn.FadeTo = function(speed,to,callback) {
return this.animate({opacity: to}, speed, function() {
if (to == 1 && jQuery.browser.msie())
this.style.removeAttribute('filter');
if (jQuery.isFunction(callback))
callback();
});
};
})(jQuery);
```

And replace (fadeIn, fadeOut, fadeTo) to (FadeIn, FadeOut, FadeTo). (the difference is on the F)

Otherwise use:

```
$(selector).removeAttribute('filter');
```

If you need some more info comment my answer and i will edit it :)
I think this is what you want. Sorry for my english. :(

Comment: Thanks CuSS - I checked out the Javascript code and it uses no fadeIn,fadeOut or fadeTo functions. You can check the code in this link http://jqueryfordesigners.com/simple-jquery-spy-effect/ - I have not changed anything in this code except the background color