# div acting like overflow:hidden even when set to visible in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, overflow, hidden, internet-explorer-7

I wrote a jQuery lightbox plugin, but I cannot figure out why the wrapper div is acting like it has `overflow: hidden` on in IE7.

I tried setting it to `visible` and `visible !important`, but it's still clipping the child element that's absolutely positioned over the margin.

Works fine in IE9 in IE7 browser mode. Shows up in IE7 on my WinXP virtual machine.

This bug is not reproducible. I tried simplifying to the bare elements in jsfiddle, but the bug did not reoccur.

[solved, so removed link]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `filter: alpha(opacity=100);` on your wrapper div after it is opened. Remove it and you will be fine. I was when I tested this...

My guess is that this stupid fr*cking **'IE only CSS'** `filter` *(excuse my french)* does some *(obviously false)* assumptions on the size of the element and is removing and redrawing the whole thing.

Edit:

I've isolated the [problem](http://jsfiddle.net/M7mRn/38/) for the people who like to test this for themselves ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/M7mRn/38/

Comment: I can remove it using web developer tools addon, but how do I implement this in my plugin?

Comment: Nevermind. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603961/jquery-animate-opacity-to-1-then-remove-the-opacity-property-to-make-it-better-l

Comment: I 'fiddled' a little and isolated the problem. It has something to do with the `z-index` in combination with the `filter` directive. http://jsfiddle.net/M7mRn/33/

Comment: My close div has a higher z-index than the wrapper though.

Comment: Yes, in my 'fiddle' I did the same. The problem doesn't occur though if you do not explicitly set the `z-index` of the wrapper div. See [the link in the edit of my answer](http://jsfiddle.net/M7mRn/38/) for the proof.